# html to json get div data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to convert html page div tag to json data and append that div in another html page.get that div that using id.

suppose there is page.html in which div tags are there, having id page1 page2 and so on.Convert those to json data and get the div tags according to their id, then append those div tags to page2.html div tag. how to do that.

this is page2.html

```
<div id="page1">
this is page1

</div>

<div id="page2">
this is page1
</div>

<div id="page3">
this is page1
</div>

<div id="page4">
this is page1
</div>
```

having div tags

I tried getting div using js but from another page
this is page1.html and want to access div of page2.html

```
function getdata()
        {
            $.get('page2.html', null, function(text){
                  alert($(text).find('#page1'));
                });
            var json = JSON.stringify(element);
            alert(json);
        }
```

I tried this but its not working.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and then show us code and effort

Comment: you can use .clone or .html using div ID and get whole content of div tag and convert that content to json

Comment: this seems an XY problem. using ajax that  way is an unusual and doubleplusungood way of data retrieval from external source. 
better, describe the exact problem. 

http://xyproblem.info/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Newspeak_words

Comment: how do I access page2.html div tag in page1.html using javascript. If this gets solved than other things can be done by the solution provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to write div object in json string , convert div into json object with all required attributes and values.
see below snippet for example.

```js
function append(){

  var element = document.getElementById("page1");
  var jsonObject = {};
  jsonObject.id = element.id;
  jsonObject.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;

  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject); // this is json for your div. 

  /// for append div and get div object back from json.
  
  var elementProto = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  
  var element = document.createElement("DIV");
  element.innerHTML = elementProto.innerHTML;
  element.id = elementProto.id;
  
  
  // append to container (in your case its page 1 or 2)
  
  document.getElementById("container").append(element);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="page1">
  <p>this div will appended </p>
</div>

<button onclick="append()">append div</button>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: the problem id page1 is in another page, not on the same page

Comment: for getting div tag try this      $.get('page2.html', null, function(text){
               var wrapper= document.createElement('div');
                wrapper.innerHTML = text;
                var divElem =   wrapper.querySelector("#page1"); // this is your div
                
                });

Comment: just a doubt, Is it possible to get data using json? your code is working fine.

Comment: did  you mean html markup into json format ? if yes than its not possible , because json needs proper structure, and if code works for you dont forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

try this code for get div content

```
function getdata()
    {
        $.get('page.html', null, function(text){
              alert($('#page1').html());
            });
jsonObj = $('#page1').html();
        var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonObj);
        alert(obj );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code spinet in `getdata()`

```
jQuery.get('page2.html',null,function(response){
    var obj = jQuery('<div/>');
    var json = {};
    jQuery(obj).append(response);
    jQuery('[id^="page"]',obj).each(function( index, object ){
        json[index] = jQuery(object).text();
    });
    console.log(json);
});
```

Comment: I'm getting data but I just want data of div tag haing id page1 but data of every div tag with id page1 page2 page 3 is appended.

Comment: what can I change If I don't want each function

Comment: If you want text of page1 then `jQuery('#page1',obj)` will be you jQuery object. instead of `each` loop

Comment: I tried this but is not working..jQuery.get('page.html',null,function(response){
        var obj = jQuery('.page');
        var json = {};
            json[index]=jQuery("#page2",obj).text();
            jQuery(obj).append(response);     
        console.log(json);
    });